# Trouble Adding Column with ALTER TABLE ADD Function

Tags: sql-server

Trying to add a column (Total_Parts) with
 `ALTER TABLE ADD`
statement but when I execute the query, it says the column I'm adding is an invalid column name and my column doesn't show up in my table.

I have similar code that is implemented elsewhere and it works so I don't know why it fails in this instance.

I've tried taking out the code that references my column in the select statement so that the column isn't referenced until the `ALTER TABLE ADD` statement but that didn't work.

```
DECLARE 
    @Total_Good_Percent float
SELECT

COUNT(CASE WHEN HMC_Place_Position IS NULL THEN 0 END) AS Parts,

COUNT(*) AS Total_Parts,    

COUNT(CASE
    WHEN Outfeed_Place_Time IS NOT NULL THEN 1      
END) AS Total_Good_Parts,                                                                       /*Total Good Parts */

(COUNT(Total_Good_Parts)*100 / (Total_Parts))/convert(float,count(*)) AS Total_Good_Percent,

COUNT(CASE
    WHEN (Reject_Place_Time IS NOT NULL AND Telesis_Stamp = '') THEN 1 
END) AS Total_Rejects,                                                                         /*Total Rejects */

COUNT(CASE
    WHEN (HMC_Place_Position IN (13, 14)) AND (Outfeed_Place_Time IS NOT NULL) THEN 1           
END) AS Total_Passed_Remeasures,                                                               /*Total Passed Remeasures */

COUNT(CASE  
    WHEN ((Reject_Place_Time IS NOT NULL) AND (Outfeed_Place_Time IS NULL) AND Infeed_Pick_Time IS NULL) THEN 1
END) AS Total_Failed_Remeasures                                                                /*Total Failed Rejects */

FROM PartData_GKN05_H
WHERE Infeed_Pick_Time >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) OR (Infeed_Pick_Time is null AND (Reject_Place_Time >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) OR Outfeed_Place_Time >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())))
GROUP BY Total_Good_Parts
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H Add Total_Passed_Remeasures int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H Add Total_Good_Parts int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H Add Total_Rejects int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H Add Total_Failed_Remeasures int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H ADD Total_Parts int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H ADD Parts int
ALTER TABLE  PartData_GKN05_H ADD Total_Good_Percent float
```

I also have a `COUNT AS` statement which I believe should create the column but it doesn't.

Comment: put a ";" at the end of statement can help.  Also, if partdata_gkn05_h has data (which seems the case), you can only add new nullable column or have a default value.

Comment: I don't see any thing specifically wrong with each of your statements there. Are you trying to reference the column in the same batch you add it? It's recommended to add the column, and then try to reference it in a separate batch. A, for example, can be see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e338e532f13de359656f1d0f5f76e47c), the first `SELECT` fails, as it references the new column in the same batch. The second `SELECT`, however, does not (as it is in a separate batch).

Comment: Shouldn't the ``` COUNT AS ``` Statement create the column within the ``` SELECT ``` statement? I have this same code implemented in another instance and it works, but in this instance, the column never gets added to the table... Seemingly regardless of the order in which I try to add the column.

Comment: @Larnu Still says "Invalid Column Name"

Comment: Wait, I see the problem. In your `SELECT` you have `COUNT(Total_Good_Parts)*100 / (Total_Parts))/convert(float,count(*))`, however, those columns don't exist in your table till **after** your `SELECT` statement. SQL statements are run top down in a batch. Your `ALTER` statements are after your `SELECT`, so they don't exist yet to be referenced.

Comment: I deleted that comment @EthanEdmondson, as I spotted the problem.

Comment: Also, however, every row will have the value `NULL` after your `ALTER` statement, so you'll need to perform some kind of `UPDATE` first. But, if you're trying to store aggregated data in your table, don't. I would suggest using a `VIEW`. If you have a column with the information in your table, it'll become stale as soon as one or more rows are updated; unless you use triggers (and that is likely a poor idea, due to the required overhead).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you, that resolved the error I was getting but my column is still not being added? It does not show up when I run my query even though it is selected with the COUNT AS statement.

Comment: Your `ALTER` statements work fine for me: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f11faad886bcb316534208dcc30437c7).

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the software I'm running my query in. Ignition by Inductive Automation. I'll try asking around in their forums I guess.

Comment: Why are you trying to add columns to that table?

Comment: Because my table doesn't already include that data (Total_Parts, Total_Good_Parts, etc.) and I need to interpret it from the table data.